# Swift - openweathermap.org api : What's wrong in my compare function?

Tags: swift, nsdate

I am using a openweathermap.org api. I am getting sunrise and sunset date and compare these. date1 is sunrise and date2 is sunset date. I'm checking if weather is true, answer is yes. But the answer is wrong. I'm comparing month,day and time. What's wrong in my code ?

Here is my code :

```
func checkDate(date1:NSDate, date2:NSDate){
    // Date comparision to compare current date and end date.
    var dateComparisionResult:NSComparisonResult = NSDate().compare(date1)
    var dateComparision:NSComparisonResult = NSDate().compare(date2)

    if dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending || dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame && dateComparision == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    {
        //result is
        answerLabel.text = "yes".uppercaseString
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }else{
        answerLabel.text = "no".uppercaseString
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to compare exactly?  What result are you hoping for?  If date1 is sunrise and date2 is sunset, then (why aren't they named that way) why do you need to compare them?  What's the code inside the `if` and `else` telling us exactly? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: if telling the weather is sunny, ele is not sunny. This is just test code sorry for the names. if nsdate<sunset and nsdate>=sunrise ,yes the weather is sunny. This is my purpose. Sorry i am new for create algorithm and programming.

Comment: So, you're checking whether it's day time or not?

Comment: Yes, i am checking day time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, you appear to be checking simply whether or not the current time is during daylight hours or not.

So, first of all, instead of reducing this to simply checking just *now*, let's make this an `NSDate()` extension that can be applied to any time.

```
extension NSDate {
    func between(firstDate: NSDate, _ secondDate: NSDate) -> Bool {
        // TODO: determine if self is between first and second date            
    }
}
```

To make this easier to read, let's come up with some convenient overloaded operators for `NSDate`, shall we?

```
func == (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) {
    return left.compare(right) == .OrderedSame
}

func > (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) {
    return left.compare(right) == .OrderedDescending
}

func < (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) {
     return left.compare(right) == .OrderedAscending
} 

func != (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) {
    return !(left == right)
}

func >= (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) {
    return (left == right) || (left > right)
}

func <= (left: NSDate, right: NSDate) {
    return (left == right) || (left < right)
}
```

Now we're ready to return to our proposed `between` method, which becomes really simply now:

```
extension NSDate: Equatable, Comparable {
    func between(firstDate: NSDate, _ secondDate: NSDate) -> Bool {
        return self >= firstDate && self <= secondDate
    }
}
```

Whether we want a "or equal to" comparison is up to our specific requirements.  But adding the operators makes this much cleaner and adds convenient operators for us to use in other scenarios, plus this is much better to write unit testing for.  And as an added bonus, we can now declare `NSDate` as [conforming to `Equatable` and `Comparable`](http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/).

---

Now, to determine if a specific time is during daylight hours is as simple as this:

```
let isDaylight = NSDate().between(sunrise, sunset)
```

or perhaps:

```
if NSDate().between(sunrise, sunset) {
    // daylight
} else {
    // not daylight
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code like this and it works !

Code :

```
func checkDate(date1:NSDate, date2:NSDate){
        // Date comparision to compare current date and end date.
        var dateComparisionResult:NSComparisonResult = NSDate().compare(date1)
        var dateComparision:NSComparisonResult = NSDate().compare(date2)

        if dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedSame || dateComparisionResult == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending && dateComparision == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
        {
            //if It is daylight outside
            answerLabel.text = "yes".uppercaseString
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }else{
             //if It's not daylight outside
            answerLabel.text = "no".uppercaseString
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            answerLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }

    }
```